# Force rbenv to install openssl?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rbenv

I have an existing version of openssl installed, however its the old version.  Upgrading to new releases of Ruby, using rbenv, does not upgrade openssl.

How do I force rbenv to upgrade?

This is under ubuntu 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rbenv is **not** a package manager. This is a good thing.

If you want to use a newer version of openssl, simply specify it when you compile ruby

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl --enable-shared
```

To see more help, use `$ ./configure --help`

---

If you're using rbenv ruby-build plugin, you can use `CONFIGURE_OPTS`

```
$ CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl" rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

Read more about [Special Environment Variables](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#special-environment-variables) for ruby-build